# Running time of Recursive Method

Tags: algorithm, runtime, time-complexity

I have written the pseudo code for  a method to calculate an entry in row i, col j of Pascal's triangle.

```
Pascal(i,j)
  if(i==j or j==0)
     return 1;
  return Pascal(i-1,j-1) + Pascal(i-1,j)
```

My problem is that I can't figure out the running time.  I know it's exponential, but I don't know how to prove it by solving a recurrence relation.

Comment: Looks like you may have some bugs in your code: in the if, you set j to 0, rather than use `==`. Also, you only return 1 - where's the return if i !=0 and j != 0?

Comment: I suggest asking your question in MathOverflow

Answer (score 0):

You'd do well to work out a few examples to see how far back you go. Remember that you have a triangle. You start at row i, then you're in row i-1. At the next step, you're in row i-2. Etc. How many rows back must you go in the worst case?

Draw the picture and do examples to build intuition. Finding a proof from a few examples with i=6 should be pretty easy.

Comment: I did just that and it seemed to me that to get the values for row n required the number of additions in the previous row plus n-1.  So, I get T(n) = T(n-1) + n-1. Is this correct?